# Azure virtual machine, can't access from internet

Tags: azure, docker, networking, cloud, virtual-machine

I have a Azure Virtual Machine with a docker-compose.

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                          COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
01c51a6b0111        yyy                       "/bin/sh -c 'ng serv…"   About an hour ago   Up 33 minutes       0.0.0.0:4300->4200/tcp   azureuser_web_app_speech_1
3701382682fd        xxx                       "java -Djava.securit…"   About an hour ago   Up 33 minutes       0.0.0.0:8087->8080/tcp   azureuser_api_speech_docker_1
```

But when I want to access my web application from my browser (http://public_ip:4300) I have a time out error.

I've already add network rules to accept requests on port 4300

Thanks for your help

Comment: Did you check the firewall rules on the VM?

Comment: Any more questions? Does it solve your problem? Please let me know if it works or not.

Answer (score 0):

For your issue, I think the possible reason is that your application is not run well or it does not listen to the port 4300 as you expect. So you can access it inside the VM through the command `http://localhost:4300` to check the port is right. And you can also go inside the container to check if the application is run well.

By the way, the NSG rules also need to check if there is a rule with a higher priority denied the port.